# Spring Boot: How to add custom name to fields of nested object in custom validation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm currently using custom validator in Spring Boot, to validate nested entity objects. But instead of displaying entityName.fieldName as invalid input error message i want simply nested objects fieldName.
e.g the two entities are User and Address like this:

```
User{
@NotEmpty
String name;
@Valid 
Address address;
// getters/setters
}

Address{
@NotEmpty
String street;
@NotEmpty
String lane;
// getters/setters
}
```

Now, when i validate user and i don't fill street for address entity it gives error like this:

```
invalid input: address.street
```

but instead of this error i want it like this:

```
invalid input: street
```

Is there any way to do it like this.

Comment: you can use split function

Answer (score 0):

You could create a customer MessageInterpolator.

Read more about message interpolation here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation